# Tkinter и команда print в консоль

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

Собственно есть такая проблема: знаю `python`, понадобился граф.интерфейс, решил воспользоваться встроенной средой `Tkinter`.
Проблема в целом такая: написал `Hello Word`, но с кнопки. Собственно кнопка должна выводить текст, но текст выводится в командную строку, в консоль.
Как реализовать вывод текста в какой-либо виджет главного окна интерфейса?

Answer (score 4):

Возможно так:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def say_hi(self):
        self.label["text"] = "hi there, everyone!"

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.f1 = Frame(self)
        self.f1.pack()
        self.QUIT = Button(self.f1)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.QUIT["fg"]   = "red"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit

        self.QUIT.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.hi_there = Button(self.f1)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello",
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi

        self.hi_there.pack({"side": "left"})
        self.label = Label(self, text='Place for hello')
        self.label.pack()

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Чуть исправленный пример из документации. Добавлена Label и по кнопке hi_there у неё изменяется текст.

Answer (score 1):

Однострочное текстовое поле
Такое поле создается вызовом класса `Entry` модуля `tkinter`. В него пользователь может ввести только одну строку текста.

```
ent = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3)
bd – это сокращение от borderwidth (ширина границы).
```

Многострочное текстовое поле
Text предназначен для предоставления пользователю возможности ввода не одной строки текста, а существенно больше.

```
tex = Text(root,width=40,
          font="Verdana 12",
          wrap=WORD)
```

Дополнительная информация: http://younglinux.info/tkinter.php